# Frame in block in poster

Tags: beamer, framed, presentations, block, posters

I am trying to make some changes in [GeoURV Poster template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/geourv-poster-template/ygvdtpypxvrq). There is a file beamerthemeGeoURV.sty inside this template, where the blocks are defined as follows

```
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{ 
\vskip.75ex
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3.5ex,dp=0.5ex,center,leftskip=-1em,colsep*=.75ex]{block title}%
\usebeamerfont*{block title}%
{\phantom{Gg}\insertblocktitle}% phantom because of baseline problem
\end{beamercolorbox}%
{\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
\usebeamerfont{block body}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1em,colsep*=.75ex,sep=0.5ex,vmode]{block body}%
\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
\end{beamercolorbox}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}{}
}
```

But I would like to have all these blocks framed, and more, these orange title blocks to be rounded. I tried to use \fbox{...}, but this didn't work. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tcolorbox` inner beamer theme:

```
\input{preamble.tex}
\input{metadata.tex}

\useinnertheme[rounded]{tcolorbox}

\tcbsetforeverylayer{
  frame style={draw=col4,line width=2mm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t] 
\begin{block}{Resum/Objectius}
\lipsum[1][1-8]
\end{block}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks perfect, but adding these two lines generate an error "LaTeX Error: File `beamerinnerthemetcolorbox.sty' not found." I also added \usepackage{tcolorbox} to the preamble.

Comment: @blahblah Is your tex distribution up to date?

Comment: I am using overleaf with Tex Live version 2022

Comment: overleaf uses a texlive2022 version from something like July or August. The tcolorbox inner theme was released in September.

Comment: You could try to upload this file https://github.com/samcarter/beamertheme-tcolorbox/blob/main/beamerinnerthemetcolorbox.sty to your overleaf project

Comment: It's working fine. Thank you! Taking the opportunity I would like to ask you if you know how to change this header color to gradient? I found that I may change this orange color (where is the title, authors, etc.) in beamerthemeGeoURV, but I would like it to be a gradient, e.g., from black to green?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, I asked a new question